# Backward search in vi-mode

Tags: vi, zsh

I just discovered the possibility to use vi-mode in zsh. Pretty awesome. But I used CTRL-r in emacs-mode pretty much and really really miss it. Is there something alike or can I get that functionality in vi-mode as well?

Comment: Common, it belongs to superuser

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can bind `history-incremental-search-backward` to any key, for example:

```
bindkey -M vicmd '?' history-incremental-search-backward
```

Comment: This works great - I bound '/' instead to replace the default search.

Comment: This works. Without losing the conventional key binding.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267007/2046462

Answer (score 37):

According to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30169

you can actually bind  in vim-mode to the history search:

```
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
```

According to a comment to the answer you can also bind  to `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`

```
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

Then you do a history pattern search with

example: `<C-R> mv * /target`

Answer (score 13):

This is the solution: up/down allows to either browse history (if field is empty) or search. Made my day.

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```